# Android webview inactive drop down

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an webview that show a dynamic list of div/tables with drop downs in it that all are set to display: none; with an visible headline link to show.
If i click on a headline the div will show up but in most cases i can't click on the drop down or if i select a option that doesn't appear correctly.
The problem occours in a element has been hidden before and the webview doesn't update after a selection on a drop down or even does allow do click it.

Comment: Can you post sample code to jsfiddle.net or staticc HTML file as it is hard to understand the problem based on plain English description. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:
`select {
     visibility: visible;
     -webkit-appearance: menulist-text;
   }`

I had similar issues and [this](http://youngliferamblings.wordpress.com/2011/08/09/select-dropdown-in-android-webview/) is what fixed it for me.